# iAd not working on iOS 6

Tags: ios5, iad, ios6

I have an iPhone app with iAd implemented and it was working fine on iOS 5.1.1. I upgrade my Xcode to 4.5 with the iOS 6 SDK to check my app for iOS 6 compatibility. The only thing that doesn't work now is the iAd. I try the 5.1 SDK simulator and it works but not on the iOS 6 simulator. I upgrade my iPhone to iOS 6 to try on the device it self and doesn't work. I test my app on my iPod and my wife iPhone with 5.1.1 and it works but not on devices with iOS 6. The point is that I have tried, test and look for answers about this issue and no one seem to have the solution.

Can anyone help me if you have the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your iAd views are in the view hierarchy. They won't get the  fulfillment notifications anymore unless they're already in the view hierarchy. They can be hidden or located offscreen, but they do have to be in the view hierarchy now. Check the iOS 6 Beta developer boards on devforums.apple.com for more information.

Comment: Don't forget to mark a comment as the answer, if any help.

Answer (score 2):

iAd and AdWhirl deprecated a few things in iOS 6, mostly due to the new screen sizes.
http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/issues/detail?id=318

Adding  `#import <iAd/ADBannerView_Deprecated.h>` should help with the compile errors, though that solution is a little kludgey.

Answer (score 1):

I added this:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

to the top of AdWhirlAdapterIAd.m and then the errors disappeared.